# add sources for rosinstall

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the package prosilica_camera using **rosinstall prosilica_camera** and I get the error

rosinstall operating on /home/mike/ros_workspace/prosilica_driver from specifications in rosinstall files  
(Over-)Writing /home/mike/ros_workspace/prosilica_driver/.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/mike/ros_workspace/prosilica_driver
ERROR in rosinstall:
No 'ros' stack detected in candidates [].
Please add the location of a ros distribution to this command.

How do I add the location of a ros distribution to that command? 
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35808/add-sources-for-rosinstall/) by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed from packages it's usually in /opt/ros/ and you literally add it.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikeS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2457/mikes/) on 2012-06-06**:
Thanks, that worked.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-07**:
@mikeS Please accept the answer on the left(using the checkmark) to give @dornhege karma and let others know they don't have to look in to this question.

**Comment by [giova](https://answers.ros.org/users/27416/giova/) on 2016-07-07**:
Hi,
I'm new in Ros, could you please explain how to do the operation described above?